# Derivation of numerical integration

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

> ### Derive the Simpson's $\frac{3}{8}$ rule
>
> Simpson's $\frac{3}{8}$ rule for integration can be derived by approximating the given function $f(x)$ with the $3^{\text{rd}}$ order(cubic) polynomial $f_3(x)$ $$f_3(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$$  Using Lagrange interpolation, the cubic polynomial function $f_3(x)$ that passes through $4$ can be explicitly given as $$f_3(x)=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)(x_0-x_3)}f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)}f(x_1)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}f(x_2)+\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}f(x_3)$$
>   \begin{align}
> I&=\int_a^bf(x)\:dx\\
> &\approx \int_a^bf_3(x)\:dx \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)\\
> &=(b-a)\times \frac{f(x_0)+3f(x_1)+3f(x_2)+f(x_3)}{8}
> \end{align}

Whenever I tried to integrate $(1)$ I completely lost. My Lecturer didn't provide any other method even all previous derivation$(\text{Simpson's }\frac{1}{3},\text{trapezoid})$ was also done by this. Lagrange method is mostly a theoretical tool used for proving those theorems. Not only it is not very efficient when a new point is added (which requires computing the polynomial again, from scratch). I feel there must be another way to derive those formula by easily and I got [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2284355/736159). But which isn't familiar with me and I failed to apply it in those derivation. 
I heartily thank if anyone explain the linked rule in details.

Comment: If the question is "how to integrate $f_3$" then you may notice that $f_3$ is just a polynomial of third degree which can be integrated easily (the computations are still tedious because the coefficients of the polynomial are somewhat clumsy)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I can integrate $f_3$ but it's tedious in exam. That's why I need an alternative approach where I can ignore such tedious integration. I linked a answer where the method of undetermined coefficients was discussed. But I failed to understood because of shortly describe. I need a bit more details(demonstration) to gasp the method.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't know you have to do this in an exam 

Comment: Ok maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1661439/631742

Comment: Thanks in advances @MaximilianJanisch. I will wait to see your work

Comment: The idea in the linked post is the same as in the one you already found: Because you know that the integral is exact for the polynomials $1,x,x^2$, you can turn the integration into a task of solving a linear equation system

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch it still need the integration $f_3(x)$ from $-1$ to $1$. and at the bottom they mention quadrature rule which still confusing me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so we're in a test and have to knock this out quickly and efficiently. Get rid of the variables and derive the rule
$$\int_0^3f(x)dx=w_0f(0)+w_1f(1)+w_2f(2)+w_3f(3)$$
Let's take some moments:
$$\int_0^31\,dx=\left.x\right|_0^3=3=w_0+w_1+w_2+w_3$$
$$\int_0^3x\cdot1\,dx=\left.\frac12x^2\right|_0^3=\frac92=w_1+2w_2+3w_3$$
$$\int_0^3x(x-1)\,dx=\int_0^3\left(x^2-x\right)dx=\left[\frac13x^3-\frac12x^2\right]_0^3=9-\frac92=\frac92=2w_2+6w_3$$
$$\begin{align}\int_0^3x(x-1)(x-2)dx&=\int_0^3\left(x^3-3x^2+2x\right)dx=\left[\frac14x^4-x^3+x^2\right]_0^3\\
&=\frac{81}4-27+9=\frac94=6w_3\end{align}$$
So we have done easy products, always a binomial times a polynomial and easy integrals and although we still have $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns, the system is in echelon form so we just have to back-substitute:
$$w_3=\frac16\left(\frac94\right)=\frac38$$
$$w_2=\frac12\left(\frac92-6\left(\frac38\right)\right)=\frac98$$
$$w_1=\frac92-2\left(\frac98\right)-3\left(\frac38\right)=\frac98$$
$$w_0=3-\frac98-\frac98-\frac38=\frac38$$
The last couple of back-substitutions and the first couple of integrals could have been skipped if we had anticipated the symmetry of the weights $w_i$.

**EDIT**: In comments I seem to have been asked to derive the two-point formula for a line connecting $2$ points in the plane. Consider the following drawing:
[image: geometry]
The line connecting the two points $P=(a,0)$ and $S=(b,3)$ has been plotted in the $uv$-coordinate plane. Also a general point $T=(x,u)$ has been plotted along the line. Line segments parallel the the $u$-axis have been drawn from $T$ and $S$ down to the $x$-axis ending at $Q=(x,0)$ and $R=(b,0)$ respectively. From geometry the triangles $\triangle PRS$ and $\triangle PQT$ are similar, so the ratios between corresponding sides are equal:
$$\frac{|PQ|}{|QT|}=\frac{x-a}{u-0}=\frac{|PR|}{|RS|}=\frac{b-a}{3-0}$$
So the two-point formula for a line is $x=a+(b-a)u/3$. You can check that when $x=a$, $u=0$ and when $x=b$, $u=3$ as required.

Now, if we want to generalize this to any interval $[a,b]$ use the two-point formula to get
$$\frac{x-a}{u-0}=\frac{b-a}{3-0}$$
So $x=a+\left(\frac{b-a}3\right)u=a+hu$, $dx=h\,du$ and
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=h\int_0^3f(a+hu)du=h\left(\frac38\right)\left(f(a)+3f(a+h)+3f(a+2h)+f(a+3h)\right)$$

Comment: thanks a lot(+1). Really it's quite less work. One last question why integrate $1,x,x(x-1),x(x-1)(x-2)?$ suppose I want use it to derive simpson's $\frac{1}{3}$ then is it change to $1,x,x(x-1)?$ But why integrate like this pattern? Again thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: The reason for the pattern is that it takes roughly $\frac23n^2$ arithmetic operations to reduce an $n\times n$ matrix to echelon form which is the task you would be faced with if you integrated $1$, $x$, $x^2$, and $x^3$. Effectively choosing the above pattern of trial functions reduces the system to echelon form in roughly $2n^2$ operations. Try it for the $3$-point formula as you suggested or the $5$-point formula and compare.

Comment: is it a typo in  $$h\int_0^3f(a+hu)du=h\left(\frac38\right)\left(f(a)+3f(a+h)+3f(a+2h)+f(a+3h)\right)$$@user5713492

Comment: @Dr.Antidode Yes, thanks.

Comment: @user5713492 I just want to thanks you again. I derive all of my numerical method formula using your answer. But I notice that I didn't understand your generalization of interval [a,b].$$\frac{x-a}{u-0}=\frac{b-a}{3-0}$$Can you tell me how it come from.And is this method called Quadrature? I will accept your answer and close this thread then.

Comment: @falamiw : The pattern results from the use of the Newton interpolation formula $$p(x)=p(x_0)+p[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)+p[x_0,x_1,x_2](x-x_0)(x-x_1)+p[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3](x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$ instead of the Lagrange interpolation formula used in the task formulation. While the Lagrange variant allows to directly read off the coefficients, the integrals are visibly more complicated.